# Cannot find Endpoint in Azure Hosted WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have searched high and low for an answer to a problem I have in hosting my WCF in Azure and have given up. Am now asking this question, hopefully someone can answer it.

I have my WCF in IIS7 working perfectly, and already have my client application connecting to it smoothly. It all works locally. I have this binding configuration in my WCF config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<standardEndpoints />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttp" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="SurveyWCFService.SurveyService">
    <clear />
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
      bindingName="basicHttp" contract="SurveyWCFService.SurveyService" />
    <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttp" contract="SurveyWCFService.SurveyService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

As you can see I have 2 endpoints, a SOAP endpoint for C# applications connecting to my service, and a JSON named endpoint for clients using REST to access it. I deployed this to Azure with the default configurations in the "Azure Web Role" template and my client can already access the given URL that Azure has generated. But here's the weird stuff:

1) Whenever my client consumes any given service methods, it brings back this exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at
http://<hostedservicename>/SurveyService.svc that could accept the message. 
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. 
See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: '<hostedservicename>'
```

It's weird because it means my app is not connecting to .cloudapp.net. So I tried using my browser to call on some service methods. Fiddler tells me the response is "HTTP 400". I've also double-checked on the generated client-config files after referencing the URL for the endpoint address, and the address is correct.

2) Azure has decided to replace my endpoints and bindings with its own. I came to that conclusion when I checked using Fiddler and checked out the wsdl files as well, here are the bottom part of the wsdl files:

**Local WSDL**

```
<wsdl:service name="SurveyService"><wsdl:port name="basicHttp_SurveyService" 
binding="tns:basicHttp_SurveyService"><soap:address location="http://localhost
/SurveyServiceLibrary/SurveyService.svc/soap"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service>
```

**Azure WSDL**

```
<wsdl:service name="SurveyService"><wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_SurveyService" 
binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_SurveyService"><soap:address location=
"http://<hostedservicename>.cloudapp.net/SurveyService.svc"/></wsdl:port>   
</wsdl:service>
```

How to make my WCF work like it was on my local environment? Is there some configuration do I need to make on my WCF? On Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the application that **calls** your WCF service. I'm under the impression that it's not using the full URL. Look for the **client/endpoint** element, like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
          ...
          <client>
              <endpoint address="http://<hostedservicename>.cloudapp.net/SurveyService.svc" ... />
          </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

Oh, and the **The remote name could not be resolved** error could also imply that you didn't get the DNS replication yet. What I tend to do in those cases is manually change my DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS server) and most of the time this works (you can change this back to automatic after a few minutes).

Comment: thanks for the tip, already checked it too, the client calls on the correct endpoint address, but the weird thing is, when I use my local WCF it generates the right endpoints and behaviorConfiguration on the client config (it generates the SOAP one). With the Azure-hosted WCF it generates some sort of default bindingConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this for those who stumbles on the same problem:

I checked the **namespace** that I provided on my service configuration file, I had a **mistype** on the namespace, ***silly me :)***